# How to get a custom MatFormFieldControl to reflect an invalid state

Tags: angular, angular-material-7

I've been following the angular-material docs which looks at creating a custom form field control:
https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

It conveniently skips over a template and reactive forms full example so i've been scrambling around trying to wire it all up.

I've had a stab at it, with varying success. Although there are other issues, i'd first like to understand how I can get this custom field to recognise when it's `invalid` so I can perform the `<mat-error>` you see below (i've removed the `*ngIf` just so I can see the state of `invalid`). The `{{symbolInput.invalid}}` is always `false`, when in fact it should be `true` as the field is required!

Custom MatFormFieldControl template use:

```
<mat-form-field class="symbol">
    <symbol-input
      name="symbol"
      placeholder="Symbol"
      ngModel
      #symbolInput="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="symbol"
      required></symbol-input>
    <button
      mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button
      *ngIf="symbol && (symbol.asset1 || symbol.asset2)"
      aria-label="Clear"
      (click)="clearSymbol()">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-error >{{symbolInput.invalid}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Custom MatFormFieldControl class:

```
export interface AssetSymbol {
  asset1: string, asset2: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'symbol-input',
  templateUrl: './symbol-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./symbol-input.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: SymbolInputComponent}]
})
export class SymbolInputComponent implements MatFormFieldControl<AssetSymbol>, OnDestroy {
  static nextId = 0;

  stateChanges = new Subject<void>();
  parts: FormGroup;
  focused = false;
  errorState = false;
  controlType = 'symbol-input';
  onChangeCallback;

  @HostBinding() id = `symbol-input-${SymbolInputComponent.nextId++}`;
  @HostBinding('class.floating')
  get shouldLabelFloat() {
    return this.focused || !this.empty;
  }
  @HostBinding('attr.aria-describedby')
  describedBy = '';
  setDescribedByIds(ids: string[]) {
    this.describedBy = ids.join(' ');
  }

  get empty() {
    let n = this.parts.value;
    return !n.asset1 && !n.asset2;
  }

  @Input()
  get value(): AssetSymbol | null {
    let n = this.parts.value;
    return { asset1: n.asset1, asset2: n.asset2};
  }
  set value(symbol: AssetSymbol | null) {
    symbol = symbol || { asset1: "", asset2: ""};
    this.parts.setValue({asset1: symbol.asset1, asset2: symbol.asset2});
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  @Input()
  get placeholder() {
    return this._placeholder;
  }
  set placeholder(plh) {
    this._placeholder = plh;
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  private _placeholder: string;
  @Input()
  get required() {
    return this._required;
  }
  set required(req) {
    this._required = coerceBooleanProperty(req);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  private _required = false;
  @Input()
  get disabled() {
    return this._disabled;
  }
  set disabled(dis) {
    this._disabled = coerceBooleanProperty(dis);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  private _disabled = false;

  constructor(
    fb: FormBuilder,
    @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl,
    private fm: FocusMonitor,
    private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {

    this.parts = fb.group({'asset1': '', 'asset2': ''});
    // Setting the value accessor directly (instead of using
    // the providers) to avoid running into a circular import.
    if (this.ngControl != null) this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;

    fm.monitor(elRef.nativeElement, true).subscribe(origin => {
      this.focused = !!origin;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    });

    this.stateChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.expandInput(this.value.asset1.length);
      if (this.onChangeCallback) {
        this.onChangeCallback(this.value);
        if (this.required) {
          const symbol = this.value;
          if (!symbol.asset1 || !symbol.asset2) {
            this.errorState = true;
          } else {
            this.errorState = false;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  onContainerClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if ((event.target as Element).tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') {
      this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').focus();
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stateChanges.complete();
    this.fm.stopMonitoring(this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }

  onKeyup() {
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  static ASSET1_INPUT_SIZE = 2;
  asset1InputSize = SymbolInputComponent.ASSET1_INPUT_SIZE;
  expandInput(currentSize) {
    //const currentSize = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value.length;
    if (currentSize >= 3) {
      this.asset1InputSize = currentSize;
    } else {
      this.asset1InputSize = SymbolInputComponent.ASSET1_INPUT_SIZE;
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
  }

}
```

symbol-input.component.html:

```
<div [formGroup]="parts" >
  <input class="asset asset1" formControlName="asset1" (keyup)="onKeyup()" [size]="asset1InputSize" maxlength="5">
  <span class="input-spacer">&frasl;</span>
  <input class="asset asset2" formControlName="asset2" size="6" maxlength="5">
</div>
```

Would someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

** **UPDATED** ** 
`symbolInput.invalid` flag now gets set after subscribing to `this.ngControl.valueChanges` and setting `this.ngControl.control.setErrors`:

```
constructor(
    fb: FormBuilder,
    @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl,
    private fm: FocusMonitor,
    private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {

    this.parts = fb.group({'asset1': ['',[Validators.required]], 'asset2': ['',[Validators.required]]});

    if (this.ngControl != null) this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;

    fm.monitor(elRef.nativeElement, true).subscribe(origin => {
      this.focused = !!origin;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    });
    this.ngControl.valueChanges.subscribe(()=>{
      this.expandInput(this.value.asset1.length);
      if (this.required) {
        if (this.parts.invalid) {
          this.errorState = true;
          this.ngControl.control.setErrors({ "invalidSymbol": true });
        } else {
          this.errorState = false;
          this.ngControl.control.setErrors(null);
        }
      }
    });
    this.stateChanges.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.onChangeCallback) {
        this.onChangeCallback(this.value);
      }
    });
  }
```

Please advise if you think this can be improved.

Comment: Similar question and my answer to it https://stackoverflow.com/a/66775511/2147247

Answer (score 1):

> Your implementation is looking good and you are always getting the `invalid` as `false` since you did not add any validation.

You can add the validation for `asset1` and `asset2` so change the following line

```
 this.parts = fb.group({'asset1': '', 'asset2': ''});
```

to

```
 this.parts = this.fb.group({
      asset1: ['', Validators.required],
      asset2: ['', Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(6)]
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel i might have got there by implementing your above solution and subscribing to this.ngControl.valueChanges and setting (when this.required is set) this.ngControl.control.setErrors to get the invalid flag to change.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is the following:

```
    get errorState(): boolean {
        return (this.model.invalid && this.model.dirty) 
               || (this.ngControl?.invalid && this.ngControl?.dirty);
    }
```

Where `model` is my local `FormControl` and `ngControl` is the parent control. So it return an error state when my control has an error or the parent is invalid.