# angular material custom form control component with custom validation doesn't trigger on form submit

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-material, controlvalueaccessor

i have implemented a custom form control with custom validation but i can't manage to mark the control as invalid once the parent form is submitted
i want that when user press submit the control gets invalidated.. so far it gets invalidated only when touching it.. in my onDoCheck i manage to read the form.isSubmitted property but i noticed that the control is still marked as "valid"

even if i build the logic and force it as invalid in my onDoChek.. that way in the parent component on submit i can't check for the control validity because i would set it after the onSubmit callback.. what am i missing here?

the ugly fix i can think of is adding

```
this.form.get('test').updateValueAndValidity();
this.form.get('test').markAsTouched();
```

on the onSubmit callback, but shouldn't it work out of the box without doing that?

here the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k5un7v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.ts

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: My answer to the  similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66775511/2147247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even my solution is not perfect I would suggest you to add NG_VALIDATORS in the `providers` of your component.

Currently your form is `valid` when the application starts and it should not.
In fact, if I run your example following properties are wrongly `true` :

```
Custom input valid: {{form.get('test').valid}} 
Form valid: {{form.valid}}
```

When I add NG_VALIDATORS in `providers` of your custom CVA component, these properties become `false`, as they should:

```
{
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
      multi: true
},
```

Just adding these lines, your form and your custom field are now invalid when the app starts, since you already have added a `validate()` method in your component.

Anyway the mat-error still doesn't show the error because of the Material component behaviors. From doc:

> mat-error: Errors are hidden initially and will be displayed on invalid form fields after the user has interacted with the element or the parent form has been submitted.
> Source: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

I don't know if you can easily change this behavior but now you can create your own styles and the form should properly work fine. Or, as other people told you, mark them as touched after submit.

I hope this advice can help you to find another way to fix your problem.

Here my StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgyug5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thank you Fabio, by adding the NG_VALIDATORS i can get rid of the setTimeout for updating validity and combining it with ```this.errorState = this.ngControl.invalid && (this.ngControl.touched || this.form.submitted);``` i can avoid manually touch the control beforehand so i can consider my problem solved: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keew1z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting and checking for validating run `markAllAsTouched()` on the form.

Comment: that is basically the way i fixed it, but shouldnt it work without me having to force the control as touched before submitting, or if i have it to touch and update validity how can i back this logic into the component instead of having to manipulate the form in the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in the Validate.

see the image below when I comment the loop section.

I'm not sure what the business requirements for your validations. but just make sure that part is returning the correct value first.

[image]

Comment: the validation works well once i interact with the widget, it returns error when nothing is selected as you see, the problem is it doesnt trigger on submit unless i force it to run with updatevalueandvalidity and markedAsTouched

Answer (score 0):

for the ones interested, i kind of found a better solution in which i don't require to mess with the form in the parent component

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7gmzya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.ts

basically all i had to do is

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    //console.log("IS REQUIRED? ", this.required)
    if (this.required && this.ngControl && this.ngControl.control) {
      this.ngControl.control.setValidators(this.validate);
      //UPDATING VALIDITY:
      setTimeout(()=> {
       this.ngControl.control.updateValueAndValidity();
      }
      );
    }
  }
```

and in ngDoCheck this:

```
this.errorState = this.ngControl.invalid && (this.ngControl.touched);
```

is now:

```
this.errorState = this.ngControl.invalid && (this.ngControl.touched || this.form.submitted);
```

this way the component behaves just like a standard angular form control, yet the solution it's not perfect i think because i had to resort to a setTimeout, so i'm leaving this as unresolved if you guys got a more elegant solution..